# Is it possible to make iTunes write rating on the file itself?

Tags: itunes, macos, mediaplayer

I'm on Yosemite (10.10.2) and using iTunes (12.1.0.50).
I read that iTunes saves the rating of the songs on its own database, not the audio files tags themselves. Is there a way to make iTunes to write the ratings on the files? Because if I move the audio file to any other place, the rating won't be recognized.

Comment: iTunes itself can't. Maybe there's some plugin that does that, but I haven't found any using google

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else needs something like this I wrote a quick piece of code using Qt 5.4 and taglib 1.14.0 that reads the iTunes database and writes the play count and rating into each mp3 file. You'll have to build it yourself or download the binary; it seems to work for me: https://github.com/carlonluca/ITunesEmbed. Backup your library before using it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it simply can't be done.

Yate Music Tagger [$20] is about the most comprehensive in- & out-iTunes database cataloguer I know & even that can't do it. It can carry the tags, but not in the tune file itself, it uses a separate CSV.

If you need tag portability, it might be the tool for you, though, as it can carry the data between different iTunes & phones.

Info at https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Yate_Music_Tagger
homepage at http://2manyrobots.com/yate/